# Core Data not finding generated managed class despite class being recognized in project

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swiftui

I'm stuck on an issue with a MacOS app I'm building. Core Data is not being recognizing a managed object class I've generated. In the below code, "WindowMO" is the codegen-generated class from the .xcdatamodel file from within the same folder as the ContentView file I'm serving from.

The error when trying to build is:
"No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Task_master.WindowMO' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?"

I've already tried setting the "module" setting in the .xcdatamodel class to "Current Product Module" and played around with module names to suss out if XCode wasn't looking in the right folders. XCode's autocomplete does recognize WindowMO, so I'm at a loss as to why Core Data would be unaware of it when trying to call .entity().

```
//In ContentView.swift:

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    let entity = Task_master.WindowMO.entity()
    @FetchRequest(entity: WindowMO.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var allWindows: FetchedResults<WindowMO>
    // ^ Problem line, specifically WindowMO.entity() call. 
...
```

Comment: Can you share WindowMO?

Comment: I  believe it was auto-generated. Trying to manually generate it gives me the following class:
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class WindowMO: NSManagedObject {

}